# Error installing inferno on Intel MBA

Tags: unix, operating-systems, macbook, c

I'm trying to install [Inferno](http://www.vitanuova.com/index.html)(an operating system) on my MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015).

Everything was OK until I hit the last step: `mk install`. Here is the error message:

```
mk: no recipe to make 'setfcr-MacOSX-386.o'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd'
mk: for j in ...  : exit status=exit(1)
```

Any ideas?

---

Extra Information:

Here is the install instruction:

```
1    Edit    mkconfig  to  reflect  your  host  environment,
     specifically  ROOT  (which  must  be  an  absolute path
     name), SYSHOST and OBJTYPE.  The comments in  the  file
     should help you choose.

2    Run  makemk.sh to rebuild the   mk  command,  which  is
     used to build everything else.

3    Set  PATH (or  path on Plan 9)  to  include  the    bin
     directory for the platform, which will now contain the
     mk binary just built.  On Unix, export  PATH.

4    Then  mk nuke to remove any extraneous object files.

5    Finally,    mk  install  to  create  and  install   the
     libraries,    limbo  compiler,  emu for hosted Inferno,
     and auxiliary commands.  The rules do that in an  order
     that ensures that the commands or libraries needed by a
     later stage are built and installed first.  (Note  that
     a  plain   mk will not suffice, because it does not put
     the results in the search path.)
```

Here is my `makemk.sh`:

```
#
#   Set the following 4 variables.  The host system is the system where
#   the software will be built; the target system is where it will run.
#   They are almost always the same.

#   On Nt systems, the ROOT path MUST be of the form `drive:/path'
ROOT=/Users/sunqingyao/Inferno

#
#   Specify the flavour of Tk (std for standard builds)
#
TKSTYLE=std

#
#   Except for building kernels, SYSTARG must always be the same as SYSHOST
#
SYSHOST=MacOSX      # build system OS type (Hp, Inferno, Irix, Linux, MacOSX, Nt, Plan9, Solaris)
SYSTARG=$SYSHOST        # target system OS type (Hp, Inferno, Irix, Linux, Nt, Plan9, Solaris)

#
#   specify the architecture of the target system - Plan 9 imports it from the
#   environment; for other systems it is usually just hard-coded
#
OBJTYPE=386         # target system object type (eg, 386, arm, mips, power, s800, sparc)

#
#   no changes required beyond this point
#
OBJDIR=$SYSTARG/$OBJTYPE

<$ROOT/mkfiles/mkhost-$SYSHOST          # variables appropriate for host system
<$ROOT/mkfiles/mkfile-$SYSTARG-$OBJTYPE # variables used to build target object type
```

Comment: You have the required software to build the OS?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not quite sure, but I did't get any error like `-bash: xxx: command not found` or so.